# JGit Clone and get the revision hash

Tags: java, git, github, git-clone, jgit

I am using the below code to clone a git repo from Java. I need to store the cloned latest revision hash.

```
localRepo = new FileRepository(path);
git = new Git(localRepo);
Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).setBranch("master")
                .setDirectory(new File(path)).call();
git.close();
```

Any clue on getting the revision hash here?

Comment: Do you mean the revision hash of the `master` branch?

Comment: Yes Rudiger. The latest cloned hash, like we see in jenkins.

Comment: There is no such thing as the 'latest cloned hash'. A repository may have many _refs_ (branches, tags, etc.) that all point to a commit. To get the commit hash of a ref, refer to the answer given by [centic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/411846/centic). Usally you would want to get the commit hash of `HEAD`. If you need to know the hash of the _youngest_  commit in a repository, let me know and I will assemble an answer of how to find the newest commit among the known refs.

Comment: I would always be cloning the master. So guess I can use "refs/heads/master". Tried out centric's answer. Head is showing up as null. Appreciate if you could show me a way to get the hash of the youngest commit. I am using this for a release management process. Hash would help me identify the present production code.

Comment: The 'present production code'  should always be referenced through a distinct ref, e.g. `refs/heads/master`. Or whatever the designated target is that developers push to when they want to release something. Hence [centic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/411846/centic)s answer should do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a `Ref` which contains the `ObjectId` of `HEAD` with the following:

```
        Ref head = repository.getAllRefs().get("HEAD");
        System.out.println("Ref of HEAD: " + head + ": " + head.getName() + " - " + head.getObjectId().getName());
```

This prints out something like this

```
Ref of HEAD: SymbolicRef[HEAD -> refs/heads/master=f37549b02d33486714d81c753a0bf2142eddba16]: HEAD - f37549b02d33486714d81c753a0bf2142eddba16
```

See also the [related snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/GetRevTreeFromObjectId.java) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook)

Instead of `HEAD`, you can also use things like `refs/heads/master` to get the `HEAD` of the branch `master` even if a different branch is checked out currently.

Comment: localRepo = new FileRepository(path);
    git = new Git(localRepo);
    Git clone = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).setBranch(branch)
     .setDirectory(new File(path)).call();
    Ref head = localRepo.getRef("refs/heads/master");Head is null showing up as null. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: works now. I made a mistake constructing the repository.